# Cargo builds fails: ld framework not found Security

Tags: macos, rust, rust-cargo, rust-chrono

Trying to run a simple program and it fails with the issue

```
note: ld: framework not found Security

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried to do some investigation and I see that chrono 0.4.19 in cargo.toml points to that. Once I remove that dependency, it stays building. I am new to the mac world and have seen various suggestion but I am very much clueless about the issue.

I tried to dockerise it and it works fine then on container, but doesn't on my mac. Can anyone please point me to the correct direction?

Comment: I am also experiencing this.  Did you ever figure out why?

Comment: Unfortunately didn't find any solution, I started an ubuntu VM and doing my project over there.

Comment: Do you happen to be using nix?  Because I am, and the fix for me was to add `pkgs.darwin.apple_sdk.frameworks.Security` to my shell.nix.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use nix :(, thanks for the advice :)

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. I can repro by making a fresh clone of https://github.com/swc-project/swc at e4216a2e6c73894942f6ae13d89711893c6fed7a and running `cargo build`. My rust stack is up to date, and I'm running MacOS Monterey 12.0.1 on an M1 Macbook Pro. Even just some hints about how to investigate this issue would be helpful.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: @Shepmaster Any advice on how to minimize down the issue I'm seeing compiling swc at git commit e4216a2e6c73894942f6ae13d89711893c6fed7a (see my comment just above yours)

Comment: @PeterBurns your comment leaves it unclear - have you  already read and tried the “Rust specific tips” I linked?

Comment: @PeterBurns I could not reproduce this issue with that commit running `cargo build` on a Macbook Air M1 with Monterey 12.0.1 (Rust Nightly).

Comment: @user4601931 thank you! I do use Nix, and that was exactly my problem.  It would have taken me a while to work that out...

Comment: Getting this error following the steps on: https://replicate.com/blog/run-stable-diffusion-on-m1-mac. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I think you're doing some custom linking which is then missing the `darwin.apple_sdk.frameworks.Security` (or whatever it's called on your system).